# Do bonuses on one weapon affect other weapons in Nier Automata?

Tags: nier-automata

For instance, when I have a weapon giving me "critical+" in the heavy attack slot; is it applied to my weapon in the light attack slot when I strike only with light attacks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throughout my research, it has noted a few times ([here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/168677-nier-automata/75085122), [here](https://fextralife.com/forums/t540936/Weapon-Effects)) that only non-combat specific weapons effect will apply regardless of which weapon is active. This is limited to two effects:

- Robot Discount
- Discount

Fortunately, these two effects do stack! So you'll get major discounts at some shots.

For combat specific weapon effects, [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/nier/comments/9sn0i8/does_a_passive_weaponeffect_affect_the_other/) reddit has researched this a little bit. The users on that community have stated that they did not see a difference in weapon speed when they have two weapons with Attack Speed Up equipped as opposed to only having one weapon equipped.

Comment: what about cypress stick and chests effect?

Comment: @arghtype I didn't find anything on that one. Lemme see what I can find

Answer (score 0):

The endurance effect of type 3 weapons and the beast weapons also works passively. This is easily seen by equipping them, pausing the game and checking your defense stat increase on the status menu.